# Adding across columns and displaying total

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this has been answered but can't find it. I have the following:

`select id, one_num, two_num, (IFNULL(one_num,0) + IFNULL(two_num, 0)) as total from posts where total > 0;`

It gives me an error:

`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'`

I think I have to do some kind of subquery. But I tried that with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use custom aliases for an expression in `where` clause either use `having` or repeat complete expression in where clause

```
select id, one_num, two_num, (ifnull(one_num,0) + ifnull(two_num, 0)) as total
from posts 
having total > 0;
```

or

```
select id, one_num, two_num, (ifnull(one_num,0) + ifnull(two_num, 0)) as total
from posts 
where (ifnull(one_num,0) + ifnull(two_num, 0)) > 0;
```

Comment: Ugh, forgot about "having" keyword. Thanks!